# Appcelerator - confusion with the tab navigastion?

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I started with the Appcelerator not long ago and I have one question. I have been struggling to find the best files organization setup so I can develop my app more easy.

The idea is that the app is divided in two parts:

1) LOGIN - Splash screen that has two buttons to open the Login Screen and New Account Screen

2) MAIN - tab window with 4 screens.

I am testing this on Android so the problem is that after I see the Splash scr, go to Login page, make the Login and get to the MAIN screen, if I press the BACK button, the application does not exit. It's going back to Login Screen. I tried to close the Login scr before I open the MAIN screen, but then when I push BACK I got returned to the Splash scr.

See the sample structure here: http://likes4fun.com/images/sample.png

I imagine that there is a solution for this problem, so if anyone can give some advice or even better give a sample code with just blank pages so I can see the navigation structure, will be great:-)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `exitOnClose : true` setting to each top window of each tab.